# Can I make landmines snap to a grid?

Tags: factorio

When playing Factorio it seems that landmines are the only object I can place where it doesn't snap to a grid. I want to make a dragon's teeth barricade with land mines interspaced but the inconsistent manual landmine placement makes it difficult to cleanly place the mines between the walls.

I tried using drones and blueprints to automate the process but very minor inconsistencies grow when scaled up using drones. I've seen pictures of other people who have their mines placed in a grid format, I just can't figure out how to do so myself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Chris Hayes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/74514/chris-hayes) in the comments, if something doesn't exist in Factorio, there's probably a **mod** for it. I haven't tested this one out myself, but quick search found there's at least this [mod by Camedo](https://mods.factorio.com/mod/camedo-snapmine) that makes mines snap to grid.

---

The best I managed in **vanilla** game was through the blueprint system, particularly though the *Snap to grid* feature that blueprints have, which makes the entire blueprint snap to an arbitrary multiple of the game's coordinates. The downside that remains is the mine *within* that blueprint will still have to be manually placed, but at least it won't accumulate additional error.

An easy way to line up the relative placement to the world grid is surrounding a square of the desired dimensions by conveyor belts and placing the mine in center by eye.

[image: Lining up the mine for blueprints]

---

You can then blueprint the mine in the center. Be sure to

- enable *Snap to grid*,
- set the appropriate *Grid size* (in my case it's Width: 2, Height: 2) - this will make the blueprint snap as if it had the respective footprint (2x2 is equivalent to e.g., turrets),
- choose *Relative* snapping - this will make the blueprint snap to the position of the cursor, instead of the multiple of the world grid. Absolute snapping is useful for blueprints that need to line up no matter where you start building them (think tile-based railroad networks).

[image: Blueprint configuration example]

---

You'll be then able to use this blueprint to place evenly spaced mines in front of your fortifications (which you can then further add to new blueprints).

[image: Example fortification with equally spaced mines]

You can read more about blueprints and their features on [the official wiki](https://wiki.factorio.com/Blueprint).

Comment: Perfect! I often try and avoid using mods because they may invalidate achievements. This is an excellent workaround!

Answer (score 4):

I did it similarly to Marty's method, without a mod. I went slightly more accurate however and used a 1x1 tile boundary instead, in my case the debug mode.
Then I blueprinted and set the snap to grid, 1 by 1. If you mouse over the flag and the mine in the blueprint preview, you will see green and yellow selection borders.

Move the mine a few pixels back and forth until you see no difference between these two borders, and you'll be set.

Make sure to save the blueprint somewhere in your library. I have a book called "Misc" for this kind of stuff. If I ever need to place mines for some build, I use that print as the basis for the initial setup, which I can then easily multiply.

Be aware that mines do not rotate visibly, but if you try to paste rotated mines over each other, they will show up red. The game does in fact track rotation of these mines, so you'll need to deal with that if you want to overlap prints of fortifications that can go around corners, etc.

Comment: Great idea to use the debug mode tile grid - I never thought of that! Also I never realized mines had rotation data stored about them, since there are other blocks in the game which can't be rotated at all. At least the good thing about mismatching rotation is that you can hold `shift` to place all eligible blocks, instead being prevented from placing the entire blueprint.